# Move to SD card not enabled in Sony Xperia M

Tags: stock-android, sony-xperia

HI i have a sony xperia M Mobile. I'm trying to move downloaded apps to SD card. For that first i installed android sdk in my pc and connected my Device in USB debugging mode. Later i started adb and changed the installed location to external card by using `pm set-intall-location 2` No errors are shown here. But after disconnecting the usb i still can't find move to SD tab in my device for any of the downloaded apps.

After setting adb i viewed adb devices i saw the devices list there is only one device connected with some name. I assumed it as my device as there are no other devices connected but how can i know that it is my device only.

My device is not rooted

Answer (score 1):

You can't move apps to sdcard on the Sony Xperia M. Unless your device is rooted.

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted. Though he doesn't explain why, this answer is right.

Comment: Are you sure that after rooting you can? I think in Android 4.3 this functionality is missing :-(

Answer (score 1):

Sony Xperia phones don't support moving applications to SD Memory card anymore. That's an official confirmation from Sony. I queried about this topic directly with them. The only thing you can do is to Rooting the device which obviously voids the warranty. Rooting is an easy process but finding a good Custom ROM is the issue.